# I want to make sure about that Apple does't change my project codes

Tags: ios, security

I'd like to learn how to ensure the security of our published applications. I work for a company who has asked me to ensure our application are secured completely (even from Apple too).

We submitted the project to the AppStore after we completed it. But how do we make sure that Apple didn't change our code?

Is it possible for Apple to modify a submitted binary to include their own code?

Is it reasonable to be concerned that Apple may steal user data (or something like that) via our applications?

How can i make sure my submitted application and sensitive data are secure?

Comment: You either trust Apple to not modify your app when they host it in their App Store, or you find another means of distribution such as an Enterprise app for internal use at your company.

Comment: If you have included your "sensitive" data unencrypted in the app then anyone who downloads it can access your data very easily. If you have encrypted the data but included the decryption key in your app then anyone with sufficient motivation can access your data. If you want to control access to your "sensitive" data then it must be downloaded on request over an encrypted link using some secure key exchange and authentication. Also you have tagged this question Xcode and Objective-C wrongly.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. And correct my question. i would say i got answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that by submitting your app to the App Store, you are pretty much explicitly trusting Apple.

Consider: they don't need to modify your binary because they control the base libraries and runtime on which your app runs.  Similarly, they control the operating system and can access any data your app stores or transmits, and you can't do much about that other than monitor your network and require your users to be on a vpn.

Pretty much the only thing you *can* do is encrypt your data.

Distributing your apps via an internal enterprise App Store might make you feel better, but it doesn't change any of the above fundamental realities.

Comment: thanks. i know how to encrypt a data. i just want to ensure Apple doesn't modify my codes. Because they get all of my project source codes before publishing my app. It looks Internal enterprise App Store may be solution for answer

Comment: @Colorist why do they get your source code?

Comment: You submit a compiled binary, not source code. It might help your career to study what a compiled binary is and at least an overview of compilers and application binaries.

Answer (score 0):

> But How do we make sure that Apple didn't change our codes?

Only Apple code review team will be able to answer your question, however 
I dont think Apple will modify your code to create backdoors or anything harmfull like that.

And even if they did that there is nothing you can do about that, simple because you are using "Apples" platform (be it their OS or App Store) and you never know about hidden backdoors. Unless they have put up some where in the iOS developer agreement that *Apple will not modify your code and will only be code reviewed and pushed to app stores* which would violate the snooping.  Even if you release your apps through other means you will be still using their OS.

I suggest you go through this [agreement](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20140909.pdf) in detail (You need to be enrolled as a developer to access that link) and if it mentions anywhere that apple will not modify your code in any way then you have something to fight for when the worst happens.